# Tricky array increment in C

Tags: c, arrays, increment

I do not understand why before if-statement ++b[1] is equal to 1, but after if-statment ++b[1] is equal to 0. Why ++b[1] does not increase inside if-statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    int b[3] = {4};
    printf("%d\n", ++b[1]); // return 1
    b[1]--;
    if((c-- && ++b[1])|| b[0]++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", b[1]); // return 0
        printf("%d\n", c); // return -1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why? Why would someone write such a code?

Comment: As in life it is best to do one thing at a time

Comment: This is  a part of my  tracking memory exercice from my university

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((c-- && ++b[1])|| b[0]++)
```

`c--` yields `0`, so `++b[1]` is not evaluated.

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

There's just some confusing operator usage going on here.

- `c--` is a *postfix* decrement, and so in the conditional statement `c` is evaluated as false (as it is `0`), before being decremented.
- Now since `&&` short circuits and only evaluates the second condition if the first is true, we do not evaluate `++b[1]`, but enter the conditional on the truthiness of `b[0]++`.